# Pass props to a component that is returned from a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello guys I have been using this hook from "WebDev Simplified"

```
import { ReactElement, useState } from 'react';

export function useMultistepForm(steps: ReactElement[], initialStep = 0) {
  const [currentStepIndex, setCurrentStepIndex] = useState(initialStep);

  function next() {
    setCurrentStepIndex((i) => {
      if (i >= steps.length - 1) return i;
      return i + 1;
    });
  }

  function back() {
    setCurrentStepIndex((i) => {
      if (i <= 0) return i;
      return i - 1;
    });
  }

  function goTo(index: number) {
    setCurrentStepIndex(index);
  }

  return {
    currentStepIndex,
    step: steps[currentStepIndex],
    steps,
    numberOfSteps: steps.length,
    isFirstStep: currentStepIndex === 0,
    isLastStep: currentStepIndex === steps.length - 1,
    goTo,
    next,
    back,
  };
}
```

so what I'm trying to do is figure out a way to pass the `goTo()` function to the last element is `Steps` which is like a summary, so that I can have some links or buttons that would take the user to that particular page and let them modify something there.

I've read that `React.cloneElement` can be used but I also seen in the react docs that  "Using cloneElement is uncommon and can lead to fragile code." so any suggestion would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the basic idea for sending props to the Step Elements. If you would like to send those only to the Last Element, you can use the same idea.

The step component should be configured to accept goTo or other props.

```js
const StepElm = ({ goTo }) => {
  return <p>Test message</p>;
};
```

Then you will pass those elements to hooks:-

```js
const { step } = useMultistepForm([StepElm]);
```

In useMultistepForm hook: change as below.

```js
const processedSteps = steps.map((step) => step({ goTo }));
return {
 step: processedSteps[currentStepIndex],
 steps: processedSteps,
...
}
```

In the Last use can use step as below:-

```js
const { step } = useMultistepForm([StepElm]);

return (
  <div>
    {step}
  </div>
)
```